# Loop through spreadsheet to create dynamic JSON objects from arrays excluding empty values?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

*(3hrs after initial post - edited examples to be more clear, including current and desired output)*

I have a spreadsheet with a few thousand rows of data, each row approximately 30 columns long.  On a daily basis this sheet has additional rows added (but never removed).  The headers are the same for all columns, but each row does not always have the same columns populated.  i.e. sometimes all 30 columns are populated, other times it may be only 20.

I want to loop through these rows and turn each row into a JSON formatted API request.  The API does not recognize null, empty or other non-Boolean values so I need some way to adjust the JSON fields for each submission to remove these empty fields from the JSON object.  Additionally, the JSON object does contain some arrays, I'm not sure if this makes a difference or not.

So far I have a looping script working but without any way to remove the fields which are empty in the google sheet.  I know I can use filter.Boolean to clean my initial array, but I don't know how to create a dynamic structure for my JSON object that can loop each row.

I am a hobby developer so I feel quite out of my depth here.  Any help would be really appreciated!

Here is what is working so far, with some comments included for reference.

```
function googleSheetsToTrackingDBAPI() {

  var data = []; // Make the array empty
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("trackingDB");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //I don't currently have headers on this sheet but they can be added.
  var dataLength = data.length; //Length of the data to use for loop
  Logger.log(dataLength);  //Checking for length of each loop

  // Now to make an array and store all my data in it. 
  for (var i=0; i<dataLength; i++) {

var ModeCode = data[i][0];
var score = data[i][1];
var attempt = data[i][2];
var difficultyCode = data[i][3];
var description = data[i][4];
var Link = data[i][5];
var season = data[i][6];
var TypeCode = data[i][7];
var languageCode = data[i][8];
var defUnit1 = data[i][9];
var defUnit2 = data[i][10];
var defUnit3 = data[i][11];
var atkUnit1 = data[i][12];
var atkUnit2 = data[i][13];
var atkUnit3 = data[i][14];
var atkSetCode = data[i][15];
var CodesAtk1 = data[i][16];
var CodesAtk2 = data[i][17];
var CodesAtk3 = data[i][18];
var defSetCode = data[i][19];
var CodesDef1 = data[i][20];
var CodesDef2 = data[i][21];
var CodesDef3 = data[i][22];

    // To filter out null, empty, etc via filter(Boolean).  It works but the JSON data is an object so this won't help with JSON structure.
    //var filteredData = data.filter(Boolean);
    //Logger.log(filteredData);

    var payload = 
          [{
            ModeCode,
            atkTeamCodes : [
            atkUnit1,
            atkUnit2,
            atkUnit3
          ],
            defTeamCodes : [
            defUnit1,
            defUnit2,
            defUnit3
          ],
          atkSetCode,
          atkAbilityCodes : [
            CodesAtk1,
            CodesAtk2,
            CodesAtk3
          ],
          defSetCode,
          defAbilityCodes : [
            CodesDef1,
            CodesDef2,
            CodesDef3
          ],
            TypeCode,
            difficultyCode,
            score,
            season,
            attempt,
            Link,
            description,
            languageCode,
          }];
      Logger.log(payload);
    
    var modPayload = JSON.stringify(payload);
    Logger.log(modPayload);

      var headers = {
          "API-KEY": 'itsakey'
      }

      var trackingDBurl = "https://text.com/textapiurl"
    
      var trackingDBparams = { 
        "method":"post",
        "contentType":"application/json",
        "headers": headers,
        "payload": modPayload
      }

    var postPayload = UrlFetchApp.fetch(trackingDBurl, trackingDBparams);
}}
```

Here is an example of a few rows from the spreadsheet (I added headers for clarity in this post, though in script I don't account for them).

| ModeCode | score | attempt | difficultyCode | description | Link | season | TypeCode | languageCode | defUnit1 | defUnit2 | defUnit3 | atkUnit1 | atkUnit1 | atkUnit3 | CodesAtk1 | CodesAtk1 | CodesAtk2 | CodesAtk3 | defSetCode | CodesDef1 | CodesDef2 | CodesDef3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Flying | 75 | 1 | Easy | Easy win | https://youtu.be/blahblahblah1 | 11 | Competitive | ENG | Unit1 | Unit2 |  | Unit12 | Unit13 | Unit14 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Small | 2 | 1 | Complex | Very difficult to win | https://youtu.be/blahblahblah3 | 13 | Competitive | ENG | Unit9 | Unit10 |  |  | Unit4 |  |  | 3 | code1 | code2 | code3 |  |  |  |

Current output;

```
[{"ModeCode":"Flying","atkTeamCodes ":["Unit12","Unit13","Unit14"],"defTeamCodes ":["Unit1","Unit2",""],"atkSetCode":"","atkAbilityCodes ":["","",""],"defSetCode":"","defAbilityCodes ":["",null,null],"TypeCode":"Competitive","difficultyCode":"Easy","score":75,"season":11,"attempt":1,"Link":"https://youtu.be/blahblahblah1","description":"Easy win","languageCode":"ENG"}]

[{"ModeCode":"Small","atkTeamCodes ":["Unit4","",""],"defTeamCodes ":["Unit9","Unit10",""],"atkSetCode":"3","atkAbilityCodes ":["code1","code2","code3"],"defSetCode":"","defAbilityCodes ":["",null,null],"TypeCode":"Competitive","difficultyCode":"Complex","score":2,"season":13,"attempt":1,"Link":"https://youtu.be/blahblahblah3","description":"Very difficult to win","languageCode":"ENG"}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{"ModeCode":"Flying","atkTeamCodes ":["Unit12","Unit13","Unit14"],"defTeamCodes ":["Unit1","Unit2"],"TypeCode":"Competitive","difficultyCode":"Easy","score":75,"season":11,"attempt":1,"Link":"https://youtu.be/blahblahblah1","description":"Easy win","languageCode":"ENG"}]

[{"ModeCode":"Small","atkTeamCodes ":["Unit4"],"defTeamCodes ":["Unit9","Unit10"],"atkSetCode":"3","atkAbilityCodes ":["code1","code2","code3"],"TypeCode":"Competitive","difficultyCode":"Complex","score":2,"season":13,"attempt":1,"Link":"https://youtu.be/blahblahblah3","description":"Very difficult to win","languageCode":"ENG"}]
```

I'm a bit lost if I can even keep this structure?  Maybe I have to move the dynamic part to the array creation and base that off of each row in the spreadsheet?  But I'm not sure how to create a JSON object new each time including only specific element names.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Comment: About `Here is an example of a few rows from the spreadsheet`, when your this sample value is used, can you provide your expected output value?

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited the post to make it a bit more clear and added current and desired output as well.  Please let me know if you need any further info.  Thank you for looking at it!!

Comment: Just wanted to clarify on this, these objects `atkTeamCodes`, `defTeamCodes`, `atkAbilityCodes` and `defAbilityCodes` do they always contain 3 elements inside? I'm trying to see if there is a pattern on your JSON structure so that it may be possible to create the JSON Object dynamic

Comment: @DiegoSanchez Those four objects may have anything from 0 to 3 elements inside.  Each record is different.  These four objects are the main cause of my challenge here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove empty (null, undefined, empty string) values from a javascript object, you can iterate over the keys with [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), and then check the corresponding value, like this:

```
var json = payload[0]
var newJson = {}
for (var key in json)
{
  if (!(json[key] === null || json[key] === undefined || json[key] === ''))
  {
    newJson[key] = json[key]
  }
}
```

Then use `newJson` in your API call.

This takes care of everything except those arrays of empty items.  That can be detected with [array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), or in the case of partially empty arrays, reduced with `.filter(Boolean)`:

```
var json = payload[0]
var newJson = {}
for (var key in json)
{
  if (!(json[key] === null || json[key] === undefined || json[key] === ''
    || (Array.isArray(json[key]) && json[key].every(function (item)
    {
      return (item === '' || item === null || item === undefined)
    }))
  ))
  {
    if (Array.isArray(json[key])) {
      newJson[key] = json[key].filter(Boolean)
    } else {
      newJson[key] = json[key]
    }
  }
}
```

or perhaps more concise/readable:

```
var isEmpty = function (x) { return (x === '' || x === null || x === undefined) }

var newJson = {}
for (var key in payload[0])
{
  var value = payload[0][key]
  if (!(
    isEmpty(value) || (Array.isArray(value) && value.every(isEmpty))
  ))
  {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      newJson[key] = value.filter(Boolean)
    } else {
      newJson[key] = value
    }
  }
}
var newPayload = [newJson]
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!  The first option (remove empty values with for...in) did work well.  However, the second option doesn't work.  As I understand the function, it's stopping execution of the script but not adjusting the overall structure of the JSON object?

I am also getting an error for the 2nd part; `payload[key].every is not a function`.

Comment: @mattuscainsgfrnc Apologies, I misplaced a parenthesis so my second example didn't work as expected. I've edited to correct that.  The `return` should not halt execution but returns from the inner [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#parameters) being passed to `every`.  I've added a third example that helps clarify that by making the callback a separate function.

Comment: Also I missed the fact that your object is wrapped in an array so I edited to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks again!  With your updates everything does execute properly.  Unfortunately, there are still some formatting issues remaining.  The two main issues after running the adjusted script;
- the parenthesis are stripped from newPayload which the API rejects since it doesn't fit JSON format.  Example: `modeCode=Small` should be `"modeCode":"Small"`
- the empty objects within arrays are still there.  For example, `atkTeamCodes=[Unit4, , ]` should be `"atkTeamCodes ":["Unit4"]`

I edited my original post to give examples of what the eventual JSON payload item needs to look like.

Comment: @mattuscainsgfrnc The first issue should be handled by using `JSON.stringify`. The second issue can be resolved with `.filter(Boolean) ` as you mentioned in your post.

Comment: `JSON.stringify`: yeah, oops.  That's an easy fix.  However, I really don't understand where `.filter(Boolean)` can work.  I can apply it in three places; original `data` or `payload` or `newPayload` (using it on `newJson` doesn't work since I believe `.filter(Boolean)` won't work with nested arrays).  In all of these cases I am left with the element still existing, even if it's empty.  Such as `atkTeamCodes=[Unit4, , ]`.  This is then rejected by the API since it only accepts valid elements.  :-/

Comment: @mattuscainsgfrnc You need to apply the filter to the individual array elements.  One way is to do that at the moment you assign them during the iteration.  I've added that to my examples.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHH.  Now I understand.  That works awesome.  Thank you so much for all of your patience and help, very much appreciated!!